# C++11 empty flag classes

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

In some of the `unique_lock` [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) in C++11 one can pass some [classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t) like a flag, i.e.

```
auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m, std::defer_lock);
```

where `std::defer_lock` is defined as

```
struct defer_lock {}
```

Why is it done this way, and not with an enum?

I tried to apply this to a small code sample, but I couldn't get it compiling:

```
class A {};
void foo(A a) {}

int main() {
  foo(A); // error: 'A' does not refer to a value
}
```

When I put the parentheses like `foo(A());` it works, but I don't see the difference to the STL. Why does this behave differently there?

Comment: [Looks like `std::defer_lock` is actually an instance of `std::defer_lock_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag). My guess as to why it's used is because it lets the compiler select the overload, instead of an ugly switch-case over an enum value (at run-time to boot).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a different type to mark a certain operation rather than an `enum` makes the choice of code path being taking a compile-time choice rather than a run-time choice. The implementations of the different functions can also be drastically different.

Comment: And this is called "tag dispatching".

Answer (score 5):

Actually, [`std::defer_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag) is not defined as you write, but as

```
constexpr std::defer_lock_t defer_lock = std::defer_lock_t();
```

That's why your version "mimicking" (badly) the standard library definition doesn't work; change your definition to eg.

```
struct A {} A;
```

and it will work. (or, try slightly more appealing `struct A_t {} A`)

Answer (score 4):

The actual code in the standard library is

```
struct defer_lock_t {};
constexpr defer_lock_t defer_lock {};
```

The first line defines a class with no members. The second line defines an object of that type. The object is used in the function calls.